# I'm getting Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null(on chrome) and this.container is null(on firefox) errors when I started using material dialog

Tags: html, angular, spring, angular-material

I have a table in my frontend that has a list of all my users from a MySQL database using a spring API. I wanted to create a material dialog that would open when clicking on a user but for some reason I'm getting a bunch of errors on firefox and chrome which are mentioned above and I haven't found anything online to help even though I followed many tutorials to create the angular dialog but i still got the same erros.

Here's my component html that has the list of users:

```
<div class="container-scroller">
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div class="main-panel">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title" style="font-weight: 600">Users List</h4>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Profile Picture</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Enabled</th>
            <th>Registered Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let u of users" (click)="openDialog()" id="myId">
            <td>{{u.id}}</td>
            <td>{{u.profilePicture}}</td>
            <td>{{u.username}}</td>
            <td>{{u.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{u.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{u.email}}</td>
            <ng-container *ngIf="u.enabled; else elseTemplate">
              <td class="text-success">{{u.enabled}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #elseTemplate>
              <td class="text-danger">{{u.enabled}}</td>
            </ng-template>
            <td>{{ u.registeredDate | date: shortDate }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

the .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { NewDialogComponent } from '../new-dialog/new-dialog.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-dashboard',
templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
styleUrls: ['../app.component.scss', './dashboard.component.scss'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
loginuser: any = {};
users: any[] = [];
constructor(private service: UserService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
this.loginuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
this.service.getAllUsers(this.loginuser.token).subscribe(u => {
  this.users = u;
  console.log(this.users);
});
}

ngOnInit() {
}

openDialog() {
console.log('selected item: ', selectedItem);
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
dialogConfig.data = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Angular for Beginners'
};
this.dialog.open(NewDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
}
}
```

and here's the new dialog html component:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>This is a Dialog title</h2>

<mat-dialog-content>

<p> Place content here </p>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
<button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="close()">Close</button> 
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

and the .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
selector: 'app-new-dialog',
templateUrl: './new-dialog.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./new-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class NewDialogComponent implements OnInit {
description: string;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewDialogComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  this.description = data.description;
}

ngOnInit() {}

close() {
this.dialogRef.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you're opening your dialog twice:

```
this.dialog.open(NewDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
```

Not sure if that is what is causing the exact error, but it's the first thing I noticed.

---

Update:

It looks now to me like this line is the error:

```
this.description = data.description;
```

I'm not seeing any property being set for "description"-- just 'id' and 'title'.

Comment: I tried removing it but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Can you paste the exact error? Is the dialog opening at all or is it way off to the side? If it's off to the side then it means the dialog hasn't been added as an entry component.

Comment: I've already added it as an entry point and It's not opening at all

Comment: Alright I just updated the answer. Hopefully that helps.